# Good way to handle ScrollView inside Pressable in react native?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

In order to dismiss the pop up keyboard when tapping outside input boxes I wrapped everything inside a pressable like

```
<Pressable style={styles.container} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
  <Slot onLayoutRootView={onLayoutRootView} />
</Pressable>
```

As a result all scrollviews inside are now working inconsistently (scrolling became only possible on elements that handled onPress). I did see that one potential fix is to wrap everything that needs to be scrollable inside more Pressable, and potentially I can also nest a Pressable inside every ScrollView but that's not ideal.

Is there a better way to handle this, with 'this' being either better way to dismiss keyboard or perhaps a way to let the scrollviews handle their events despite being inside a pressable?

Thanks.